# "Must be logged in to vote" when deleting my question

Tags: support

I tried to delete a question of mine, and even though the page looked like I was logged in (I guess my login timed out, the page has been open for a 8+ hours without me interacting with it), when I pressed delete I got an error saying "You must be logged in to vote".

Is that message a bug, as I wasn't trying to vote on anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as the backend is concerned, deletion is a vote.

Consider that we require 3 community members to cast delete votes for a post to be deleted - those *are* votes.

That the question is yours, and that in such a case only one vote is required doesn't change that it is a vote.